# Is there a way to automatically delete list metadata from stored ListField in mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongoengine

I am currently working with mongoengine in python. When I store a Document with a list variable and I "get" it after, mongoengine adds some metadata to the list. How can I get rid of the metadata?

```
class Example(Document)
   key = StrinField(primary_key = True)
   lis1 = ListField()

lis2 = [1,2,3]

obj = Example(lis1 = lis2, key = "123")
obj.save()

obj0 = Example.objects.get(key = "123")
print(obj0.lis1)

>> Output is the list plus metadata like _dereferenced, _instance and _name
```

My approach is to save all the lists as serialized string, but there must be a better solution to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(MongoEngine contributor here) MongoEngine indeed adds some metadata to the lists , it uses a subclass of the builtin `list` class behind the scene. Those aren't stored in MongoDB, they allow MongoEngine to deal with  auto de-referencing or track changes that are applied on the document instance. They should be harmless to your application since they can be manipulated as standard python lists.

Trying to get around it isn't a good idea as its part of the internals of MongoEngine.